# How do I Filter one or multiple PivotTable Field using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, pivot-table

I have a workbook with multiple pivot tables. I have been writing macros to filter a specific field ("YEAR_FW") on the pivot tables based on cell range that lives on a different sheet. After a bunch of trial and error I decided to write separate code for each Pivot table. I was able to filter most of the pivot tables but there are some that give me an error.

Here is the cell range:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP6Ew.png)

Here are the pivot tables(the first one got filtered):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7jvs.png)

The first table code that worked:

```
Sub Filter_dip4wk()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B3:B58")
Dim ptb As PivotTable
Set ptb = Sheets("DIP COAT TABLE 4week").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Dim fld As PivotField
Set fld = ptb.PivotFields("YEAR_FW")
           
    With fld

    Dim Item As PivotItem

    For Each Item In .PivotItems
     Item.Visible = True
    Next Item
     
    For Each Item In .PivotItems
        Item.Visible = False
        Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In rng
                If Item.Caption = cell.Text Then
                    Item.Visible = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cell
    Next Item

    End With

End Sub
```

The second table code and error (basically just changing pivot table name):

```
Sub Filter_dip4wkt2()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B3:B58")
Dim ptb As PivotTable
Set ptb = Sheets("DIP COAT TABLE 4week").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Dim fld As PivotField
Set fld = ptb.PivotFields("YEAR_FW")
           
    With fld

    Dim Item As PivotItem

    For Each Item In .PivotItems
     Item.Visible = True
    Next Item
     
    For Each Item In .PivotItems
        Item.Visible = False
        Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In rng
                If Item.Caption = cell.Text Then
                    Item.Visible = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cell
    Next Item

    End With

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTpB9.png)

I think it is because the second pivot table has a row field. I tried making changed to PivotItem part but still got errors. Any ideas? I am new to VBA/Macros so apologies if I missed out any details.

Comment: After setting all the items visible in the first loop, why are you setting them all to hidden in the second loop, only to then make some of them visible again?  You can't hide *all* items - at least one needs to be visible, so set them all visible and then just hide the ones with non-matching captions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I figured I'm identifying the items that are hidden and not actually setting them as such. Do you have any resources where I can learn more on this topic?

Comment: `Item.Visible = True` sets the visibility, it doesn't test for the current state.  `If Item.Visible = True Then` would allow you to check the visibility without altering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub Filter_dip4wkt2()

    Dim rng As Range, fld As PivotField, itm As PivotItem
    
    Set rng = Range("B3:B58") 'ideally specify a worksheeet here...
    
    Set fld = Sheets("DIP COAT TABLE 4week").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("YEAR_FW")
           
    fld.ClearAllFilters 'first set all visible
    
    For Each itm In fld.PivotItems
        'look for the caption in rng
        If IsError(Application.Match(itm.Caption, rng, 0)) Then
            itm.Visible = False 'hide non-matches
        End If
    Next itm
    
End Sub
```